# Newly put together wooden bed and the one screw bolt on the headboard decides to thread?

Tags: wood, wooden-furniture, bedroom

I just recently bought a new wooden framed bed, flat pack basically.
Everything is fine, all except this one long screw/bolt that decided to thread inside the headboard. I applied the same pressure as to all the rest of the places to fasten together, just this one wanted to be weak and to continuingly turn. And now the headboard, although tight on the leg but the top part where threaded jerks and creaks. How can I fix this? 
Considering it's just a long bolt screw that passes through the top of the leg into the headboard, using a supplied alankey, I'm guessing as in previous answers to some questions is a larger similar bolt screw??

Comment: is there a missing fitting of some sort? .... perhaps the long bolt is actually threaded into wood instead of metal .......... can you post some pictures?

Comment: could it be missing a threaded insert? can you use a lag bolt instead, or will it be ugly? if ugly, then you might consider driving a wood screw in next to the stripped original; it won't be good to remove and replace very many times, but it might be enough for your use.

Comment: It's a black 120mm allan head bolt that screw via the leg into the main headboard frame.  Because this one out of the six fittings decided to over turn at the point when I stopped with all the others, just as it got tight. It's held it to the leg post but by millimetres move that smidge to creak. Searching online for similar bolts, they're either right colour wrong size, or right size wrong style. I don't think wood glue is going hold it tight as it needs to.

Comment: good quality wood glue is stronger than the wood